# JavaFX: bind node to cell in gridpane

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I'm trying to bind a node in a gridpane to it's column width and row height. As of now, the hbox fills it if the content are smaller than the cell, but if the hbox is too big, then grows bigger then the cell.

[image]

You can see the bottom of the hbox with the border has grown beyond the bottom of the cell.

How do I bind the hbox.maxHeightProperty to the height of the cell?

```
  hbox.maxHeightProperty().bind([???].heightProperty());
  ROW_CONSTRAINT = new RowConstraints(30, 30, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.TOP, true); // all rows other than the header has this constraint.
```

Comment: You need to add more information. A `Gridpane` row height is typically the height of  the highest node in it. For more efficient help and avoid many clarification questions post [mcve]

Comment: The reason I left it somewhat open is because I felt like this was enough information and I didn't want the answer to be too specific so that others with the same issue can also reference it. It is just a normal gridpane. Nothing special and there is a LOT involved.

Comment: [By default, rows and columns will be sized to fit their content; a column will be wide enough to accommodate the widest child, a row tall enough to fit the tallest child](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

Comment: You should not do this. `GridPane` generally resizes itself to fit its children. Trying to do a reverse relationship is going to cause some kind of cyclic dependency. What you probably need is to set the child nodes' `minHeightProperty()` and `maxHeightProperty()` to the correct value. *Edit*: you need to give a concrete [mcve] to explain why setting max height to `Double.MAX_VALUE` doesn't work. This may need `hbox.setMinHeight(HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE)`.

Comment: Okay. The reason is because other then the header row which has a fixed height, all of the other rows have the following constant. `ROW_CONSTRAINT = new RowConstraints(30, 30, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.TOP, true);`